# Macrodef and "local properties"

Tags: ant, macrodef

I am trying to move a file (specified by a pattern) to a given location in an Ant macrodef:

```
<macrodef name="extract">
    <attribute name="package"/> 
    <sequential>

        <!-- the path will contain the unique file in extracted regardless of the name -->
        <path id="source_refid">
            <dirset dir="${dep}/lib/@{package}/extracted/">
                <include name="@{package}-*"/>
            </dirset>
        </path>

        <!-- this is not working: properties are immutable -->
        <property name="source_name" refid="source_refid"/>

        <move
            file="${source_name}"
            tofile="${dep}/@{package}/"
            overwrite="true"
        />

    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This will work just once as `${source_name}` is immutable.

An option would be to use the variable task but I didn't find a way to assign a refid to a `var`.

Is there a way to have something similar to local variable in a macrodef? Or (XY problem) is there a better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Ant 1.8 you can use the [`local` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) for this.  For example:

```
<local name="source_name"/>
<property name="source_name" refid="source_refid"/>
```

Your example is just the sort of thing `local` is for!